# Exception handling, error record info needs to be stored in a different table on postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO main (name, created) VALUES (i_name, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
AT TIME ZONE 'GMT');
EXCEPTION WHEN UNIQUE_VIOLATION THEN
--    RETURN 'error: already exists';
exec 'INSERT INTO error_main (name, error) select (name, 
''UNIQUE_VIOLATION'') from main'; 
END;
```

if it's possible to store the records which has known errors and specific exception handle has been done. and store this column info in a different table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a dynamic SQL for that, try a simple `INSERT`:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO main (name, created) 
    VALUES (i_name, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'GMT');
EXCEPTION WHEN UNIQUE_VIOLATION THEN
    INSERT INTO error_main (name, error) 
    SELECT i_name, 'UNIQUE_VIOLATION';
END;
```

Comment: 1.I can get all the records which has this exception, in case there are multiple rows having same issue.                                                                     
 2.is the Stored procedure will get terminated after first error encounter or it'll go till last record, even if the errors were encounted.

Comment: When an exception is handled (like in this case) it does not exit a function, a code below the block will be executed. So you can have more than one block `BEGIN ... EXCEPTION ... END`. You can also place an exception block inside a loop.

Comment: EXCEPTION WHEN UNIQUE_VIOLATION THEN
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO error_main (name, error) 
        SELECT i_name, 'UNIQUE_VIOLATION'
        END;

I think you want me to add a new block like this.
If i have 10 records in the main table and 2,4,6 row has this exception then i will get only these 3 names in the error_main table?

Comment: You cannot have 3 unique violations with the same name. If the inserted names are different, then yes, you can get info about them all in the error table. But this is probably case for using a loop.

Comment: i need to use any loop here or it'll exec row by row and filter out the error row details to the desired table. This a sample code , i'll be using multiple exception and provide separate error message for better understanding and i;m also using a record variable to create a generic script for multiple tables. That's the reason i used exec command in my code.

Comment: the number of exception count should match with the number of records in error table with respective column details, which may be a primary key of source table to get the record details later point of time.

Comment: This'll be my final question please help me on this. Yes or No. on the records details.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you well. You can use multiple exception blocks for multiple rows. You cannot catch multiple exceptions for a single row. If it's not clear, try to describe it better in a new question (with a new example).

Comment: no, please tell me if there's only one exception present and table has 100 recs and 20 of them has satisfies that exception, shall i get 20 name or any column from source table respective to that exception in error table, so 20 rows wiil be there in error table in the end, is it be the scenario on the above case or i need to use any loop

Comment: No, the exception will be catched only once. You'll have an info about a single row in the error table.

Comment: so, how can i get all the rows which has error on it.

Comment: It's impossible. A query may be successful or may fail raising an exception. If it fails on some row, there is no need to check other rows and the server never do this.

Comment: Is there any function which does work of isdate, to check whether a string column which contains timestamp is a valid timestamp or not. Have used isfinite(timestamp) but if it's not timestamp it's getting error out , it's output is Boolean but instead of false it errors out.

Comment: Please, ask a new question.